# Charge and its relationship to Voltage

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I was working on a model to describe the voltage between two metal plates (like in a battery) and came up with this model. I wanted to see if my physics and math were right.

So I started out assuming the two metal plates are conductive and placed parallel to each other. I also assumed that the plates are basically two-dimensional and exist in the yz plane. So, looking at the negative plate, the electric field generated by a single charge on that plate is

$E=\frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{|\vec{r}|^2}$

as given by Coulomb's Law where $q_0$ is the elementary charge of an electron.

$\vec{r}=\langle x,y,z\rangle$

The electric field generated by a "line" of charges on that plate is

$$E_l= 2 \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{x^2+y^2+z(i)^2}$$ where

$z(i)=i\Delta l$

$\Delta l = \frac{l}{n}$

$z(i) \in  [0,l] $ where $l$ is half the length of the plate and n is the number of electrons on that "line" on the plate. Then we sum up all these "lines" on the plate to get the electric field generated by the entire plate so

$$E_T= 4 \sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{x^2+y(p)^2+z(i)^2}$$

where

$y(p)=p\Delta w$

$\Delta w = \frac{w}{n}$

$y(p) \in  [0,w]$

and w is half the width of the plate. Now, assuming that the charge is "substantial" enough to produce a non-trivial voltage we can take

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} z(i) = z$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} y(p) = y$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}E_T= 4 \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{x^2+y(p)^2+z(i)^2}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}E_T \Delta l \Delta w= 4 \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\Delta l \Delta w$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}E_T \Delta l \Delta w = 4 \int _0 ^ w \int _0 ^ l \frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{x^2+y^2+z^2}dzdzy$$

Then, we integrate with respect to x to get voltage so

$$V \sim \frac{4}{\Delta l \Delta w} \int _0 ^B \int _0 ^ w \int _0 ^ l \frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{x^2+y^2+z^2}dzdydx$$

Assuming the distance between the plates is B.

So now for the total voltage, we get

$$V_T \sim \frac{4}{\Delta l \Delta w} \int _0 ^B \int _0 ^ w \int _0 ^ l \frac{kq_0\hat{x}}{x^2+y^2+z^2}dzdydx + \frac{4}{\Delta l \Delta w} \int _B ^0 \int _0 ^ w \int _0 ^ l \frac{k(-q_0)(-\hat{x})}{(B-x)^2+y^2+z^2}dzdydx$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is my math and my physics correct and is there any other factors I should consider in my model?